# json_encode adds double quotes instead of spaces

Tags: php, mysql, json, double-quotes

I am trying to work around a problem reading data from mysql and passing them to my page throught php.
My task is to insert data read from mysql directly into a js function.
The code is:

```
while($row = $query_ope->fetch_assoc()){
  $data = array("str_id" => $row['Id'],
                "str_rag_sociale" => $row['Rag_Sociale'],
                "str_indirizzo" => $row['Indirizzo'],
                "att_luogo" => json_decode($row['Comune']),
                "str_cap" => $row['Cap'],
                "str_reparto" => $row['Reparto']
                );
  $content .= '<tr class="cal_body">'.
                <td class="btn_icon icon icon-setup" onclick=modUt('.json_encode($data).')></td>'.
              '</tr>';
```

The problem now is that data from db fields that contains spaces inside it (for example, when $row['Comune'] = "some text") is parsed as followed:

```
onclick=modUt({...,"att_luogo" : "some" text","str_cap"....})
```

putting a double quotes after first word some, and this is a problem because my js function fail.
I am getting crazy trying to understand why.

Comment: If Comune is `some text` why are you running `json_decode()` on it?

Comment: Look at the code highlighting. You are missing a `'`

Comment: AJAX would probably be simpler

Comment: @Devon: i am using json_encode to pass data from PHP to JS
@ RiggsFolly: the single quote you say is missing, I wrongly did not put it inside my message code, but there is inside my real code. Anyway AJAX would be better, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to html encode your html attribute

```
$content .= '<tr class="cal_body"> 
            <td class="btn_icon icon icon-setup" onclick="'.htmlspecialchars('modUt('.json_encode($data).')').'"></td>'.
          '</tr>';
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, really.
I tried as you recommend me and it works! I understood what was my fault.
Do you think my is the right way to read data from db, or maybe should I write data better encoded, and then read them without special functions (like htmlspecialchars)?

Bye

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to encode your data in the database, encode it when and where it needs to be encoded.